# Undefined property when accessing properties from a parent class

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to access a property from class A using class B when class B is a child of class A and should inherits its properties using "extends".

Basically, I have:

```
class A{
    function __construct(){
        $this->foo = 'foo';
    }
}

class B extends A{
    function __construct(){
    }
}
```

Now, using

```
$B_obj = new B();
echo $B_obj->foo;
```

Returns

```
Notice: Undefined property B::$foo
```

I know I should put "protected" somewhere: I tried in front of the construct function in class A but it did not work.

Thanks for your precious help

Comment: You have to define `foo` property in `A` class

Comment: Didn't I do it using $this->foo in the construct function?

Comment: @Vincent you did an implicit declaration of the property. This works and is quite okay, but not very elegant. It is more elegant to declare any property explicitly so that you can set its visibility. Furthermore, you can gather an quick overview of all available properties in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in the constructor of class `B()`

```
parent::__construct();
```

this basically runs the constructor of the parent

Comment: When I do so just under class B extends A{, I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION". Also, I would need to have class B keep its own constructor.

Comment: My bad, I must use parent::__contruct(); inside B constructor.

Comment: @Vincent I'm glad you fixed it :)

Comment: @Vincent you can add `parent::__contruct();` at the end of `B`'s constructor, then it'll first run `B`'s constructor's code and then `A`'s

Comment: This advice would work even better if it was spelled with an "s": parent::__construct();